# WPF Draw tree structure with rectanges on top of each other

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, listbox, treeview

I have a tree structure which I use in a treeview like this

[image]

The root is in an `ObservableCollection<Component>` object. A `Component` has a x, y, width, height, children and name property. I want to use the same tree structure to draw each `Component` with `Rectancle` with child objects drawn on top. Something like this

[image]

I have tried with ListBox like this

```
<!-- in Resources -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Component}">
        <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
                <Rectangle Cursor="Hand" Fill="AliceBlue"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>



<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentsToDraw}"
         x:Name="listBox"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

But can't get it to draw anything but the first levet of my tree. 
Also tried with a Treeview but can't get it to stop drawing my `Component` objects like a stackpanel.

Hope anyone has a solution or better way to go.

PS. I didn't include the 'Solution' element in the drawing on purpose.

Comment: How do you set X,Y? global or relative?

Comment: A UserControl might be a better fit here because you get way more control over it. Start with a StackPanel of Canvases and add each nested item to its parent Canvas.

Comment: @sTrenat I was thinking about relative if I could get this tree structure to work. Else global could work as well i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept defining X,Y, in your model, you can do this with little styled treeView:

Here is Xaml:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentsToDraw}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Component}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentsToDraw}">
            <Grid Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Background="{Binding Color}">
                <TextBlock Margin="8,5,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Canvas>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Style>
                                </ContentPresenter>      
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>           
</TreeView>
```

You have here style for ItemTemplate, to makde ContentPresenter as Canvas, and HierarichalDataTemplate, to made your dataTemplate look like Rectangle with some text.

Here is model i used:

```
public class Component
{
    public Component() { }
    public ObservableCollection<Component> ComponentsToDraw { set; get; } = new ObservableCollection<Component>();
    public double X { set; get; }
    public double Y { set; get; }
    public double Width { set; get; }
    public double Height { set; get; }
    public Brush Color { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

And, in ViewModel, too made your controls, you'r writing something like:

```
var Solution = new Component() { X = 0, Y = 0, Height = 300, Width = 500, Name = "Solution", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)};
var PC = new Component() { X = 0, Y = 0, Height = 300, Width = 245, Name = "PC", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) };
var PC2 = new Component() { X = 255, Y = 0, Height = 195, Width = 245, Name = "PC2", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) };
var SubDrawingComponent = new Component() { X = 50, Y = 50, Height = 200, Width = 150, Name = "Drawing Component", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow) };
var DrawingComponent = new Component() { X = 255, Y = 205, Height = 42.5, Width = 245, Name = "Drawing Component", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow) };
var DrawingComponent2 = new Component() { X = 255, Y = 257.5, Height = 42.5, Width = 200, Name = "Drawing Component2", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow) };
Solution.ComponentsToDraw.Add(PC);
Solution.ComponentsToDraw.Add(PC2);
Solution.ComponentsToDraw.Add(DrawingComponent);
Solution.ComponentsToDraw.Add(DrawingComponent2);
PC.ComponentsToDraw.Add(SubDrawingComponent);
ComponentsToDraw.Add(Solution);
```

For each item in `Drawing Component`, you declaring X and Y, which are Relative to it's parent.
Here is how it looks:

[image]

I know, i wrote some fields with PascalCase, sorry about it :D

Comment: I will try your solution as soon as I have time :)

Comment: It is almost perfect. But for some reason I can't get the z index to work. The sub Components are hidden behind their parent

Comment: Are you sure you set it correctly? I mean, for children, parent ZIndex +=1?

Comment: You can copy paste that code, even into empty app in mainWindow, and see that it works as on the screen, there is nothing more

Comment: @smok, i Checked now, this works even without Z.Index, i updated answer to remove this.

Comment: It seems to be all good when running, but the designer for some reason hides the children behind the parent. But I can live with that.

Comment: How do you check this in Designer?:D

Comment: I have added a few more HierarchicalDataTemplates and when I put the cursor on the one for DrawingComponent, a outline of the one that should be a child of PC in the example is shown in the designer. But I can only se the outline, the text and color is not shown